# Can't query edges in OrientDB anymore

Tags: orientdb

When I try to query:

`select out('teaches') from Course`

OrientDB returns empty lists, while the edges that I'm trying to find do exist.

Also, in the graph editor, the edges options won't show up anymore:

[image]

Normally, I can choose edges by hovering over the arrows. Now it doesn't do anything.

I've noticed that this started to happen when I started indexing my edges with a unique hash key. Does this have anything to do with it?

I'm using OrientDB version 2.0.5.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, it didn't work because I was using an `UPDATE` command.

`UPDATE teaches SET in = #12:1, out = #13:1 UPSERT WHERE in = #12:1 AND out = #13:1` will create the edge (record) if it does not yet exist, but you won't be able to query it.

`CREATE EDGE teaches from #13:1 to #12:1` does work and you will be able to query it.

Not sure whether this can be considered a bug...